# combobox datasource binding affects other instance of combobox set by same data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three different combobox which I assign same value thru datasource but every selection change affects other instance. How can that be avoided?

```
private void getVendorList()
{
  DataTable data = this.vendorService.GetAllVendors();
  this.LoadDataGridView(data);

  //set vendor combobox datasource
  comboAddProdVendorId.DataSource = data;
  comboAddProdVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboAddProdVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";

  comboSearchProdVendorId.DataSource = data;
  comboSearchProdVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboSearchProdVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";


  comboAddTransacVendorId.DataSource = data;
  comboAddTransacVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboAddTransacVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Copy` the DataTable before assigning to datasource.
Try this:

```
private void getVendorList()
{
  DataTable data = this.vendorService.GetAllVendors();
  this.LoadDataGridView(data);

  //set vendor combobox datasource
  comboAddProdVendorId.DataSource = data.Copy();
  comboAddProdVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboAddProdVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";

  comboSearchProdVendorId.DataSource = data.Copy();
  comboSearchProdVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboSearchProdVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";


  comboAddTransacVendorId.DataSource = data.Copy();
  comboAddTransacVendorId.ValueMember = "Id";
  comboAddTransacVendorId.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```